# Swift Array Not Returning All Values

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, indexing

I am working on creating a simple voting application for IOS. I created a tableviewcontroller that I want to load the category names to from an Array.

My problem is the array is only returning the last value in the collection ("Mr.Lincoln).

What I am looking to do is have each category name display in a cell so a user can select it and the options show on the next view controller based on what cell was clicked.

The section of the code that shows the for in loop to return the cell is

```
for categoryText in list {
    cell.textLabel?.text = categoryText.categoryName
}
```

---

```
//
//  CatagoryTableViewController.swift
//  xlsxreaderwriter
//
//  Created by Ahmeeya Goldman on 2/11/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 Ahmeeya Goldman. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class CatagoryTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var list = [Categories]()

    var myIndex = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        list.append(Categories(categoryText: "In The Mix", choiceA: "Ivy Smith", choiceB: "Shay West", choiceC: "Donald Allen", choiceD: "Zay (Wooo)"))
        list.append(Categories(categoryText: "Best Male Organization",choiceA: "People Standing United", choiceB: "Young Kings Movement", choiceC: "Gentlemen Qualities", choiceD: "" ))
        list.append(Categories(categoryText: "Best Female Organization", choiceA: "RSVP", choiceB: "STARS", choiceC: "NCNW", choiceD: "BSLS"))
        list.append(Categories(categoryText: "Best Dancer", choiceA: "Ansord Rashied", choiceB: "Donald Allen", choiceC: "Isis Ferguson", choiceD: "Jada Mosoey"))
        list.append(Categories(categoryText: "Most Likely To Brighten Your Day", choiceA: "Bar'rae Choice", choiceB: "Tytiana Jackson", choiceC: "Ivery Tanner", choiceD: "Chinonye Agu"))
        list.append(Categories(categoryText: "Best Modeling Troop", choiceA: "Ziana Fashion Club", choiceB: "We R 1 Family", choiceC: "", choiceD: ""))
        list.append(Categories(categoryText: "Best Male Friend Group", choiceA: "Quincy, Kraig, and Kiefer", choiceB: "WOOO", choiceC: "Kevin, Ivery, Kendell, and Marc", choiceD: "Dre, Eli, Jafari, and Ryan"))
        list.append(Categories(categoryText: "Best Female Friend Group", choiceA: "Omolara, Xela, Reggie, and Shania", choiceB: "Dior, Ashleigh, Tanya, Asha, Jazamine, and Aliea", choiceC: "Damo, Dani, Ty,Tati, and Ivy", choiceD: "Ahmani, Leshay, and Nyia"))
        list.append(Categories(categoryText: "Best Dressed Male", choiceA: "Dane Tyree", choiceB: "Ajamu Davis", choiceC: "Taj Green", choiceD: "Isiah Thomas"))
        list.append(Categories(categoryText: "Best Dressed Female", choiceA: "Imani Stamford", choiceB: "Ivy Smith", choiceC: "Tyler Murray", choiceD: "Kam"))
        list.append(Categories(categoryText: "Best DJ", choiceA: "Dj Topchoice", choiceB: "Dj Mizzy", choiceC: "Dj Che", choiceD: ""))
        list.append(Categories(categoryText: "Best Clothing Line", choiceA: "Visonary Society", choiceB: "Rare World", choiceC: "Handwritten", choiceD: "Soigne Y Pree"))
        list.append(Categories(categoryText: "Best Clothing Line", choiceA: "2016", choiceB: "2015", choiceC: "2014", choiceD: "2013"))
        list.append(Categories(categoryText: "Best Miss Lincoln", choiceA: "2016", choiceB: "2015", choiceC: "2014", choiceD: "2013"))
        list.append(Categories(categoryText: "Best Mr Lincoln", choiceA: "2016", choiceB: "2015", choiceC: "2014", choiceD: "2013"))
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let count = list.count
        return count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath)

       **for categoryText in list {
        cell.textLabel?.text = categoryText.categoryName
        }**
        print(cell)
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        myIndex = indexPath.row
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showNominees", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `list.count` return?

Comment: It returns 15 cells because the array has 15 categories. The for categoryText in list {} code makes all the cells title equal the last item in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be using a loop in your `cellForRowAt`. Get the value specific to the given `indexPath`:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath)

    let category = list[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = category.categoryName

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to iterate over every element in **cellForRowAt** Instead do this:

```
cell.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row].categoryName
```

Comment: Thanks for your assistance

Answer (score 0):

You need to get value at index using indexPath :

**But in `category.categoryName` or in your struct the value of `categoryName` not define.**
I think you assign default value to variable `categoryName` which is  `categoryName = Mr.Lincoln`

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath)

    let category = list[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = category.categoryName

    return cell
}
```

Comment: How is this answer different from @rmaddy's !

Comment: @triandicAnt look at bold suggestion.

Comment: @triandicAnt All of the answers were posted within a minute or two of each other. It's fine.